# Sqlite Data To CSV file in android

Tags: android, sqlite, export, export-to-csv

This is my code when i run this it does not store or generate any file in my sd card. I dont know where i'm doing mistake sorry for mistake as im begginer in programming

```
 List<ClientModel> list = new ArrayList<ClientModel>(); //My Model
        DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext()); //My DBHelper Class
        list = db.getAllClientList(); //My Method to get all data from database

        File exportDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), ""); //

        if (!exportDir.exists())
        {
            exportDir.mkdirs();
        }

        File file = new File(exportDir, "Abc.csv"); //File Name


        //writing data to a txt file

        try {

            file.createNewFile();
            CSVWriter csvWrite = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(file));   //Writing data in csv file
            for (int index = 0; index < list.size();) {
                String arrStr[] = { String.valueOf(list.get(0))};
                csvWrite.writeNext(arrStr);

            }
            csvWrite.close();

            //But Above Code is not working for me

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: have you given write permission in manifest?

Comment: Yeah i've added already <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: what error u receiving in `catch` block?

Comment: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied) showing me in debug. but i've already added permission

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to check runtime `permission` for Api 23:

try this:

```
if(isStoragePermissionGranted()){
        Save_file();
    }
```

Now add this methods in your activity:

```
    public void Save_file(){    
        File exportDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), ""); //

                if (!exportDir.exists())
                {
                    exportDir.mkdirs();
                }
                File file = new File(exportDir, "Abc.csv"); //File Name
                //writing data to a txt file
                try {

                    file.createNewFile();
                    CSVWriter csvWrite = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(file));   //Writing data in csv file
                    for (int index = 0; index < list.size();) {
                        String arrStr[] = { String.valueOf(list.get(0))};
                        csvWrite.writeNext(arrStr);

                    }
                    csvWrite.close();

                    //But Above Code is not working for me

                } catch (IOException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

public  boolean isStoragePermissionGranted() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.v(TAG,"Permission is granted");
            return true;
        } else {

            Log.v(TAG,"Permission is revoked");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
            return false;
        }
    }
    else { //permission is automatically granted on sdk<23 upon installation
        Log.v(TAG,"Permission is granted");
        return true;
    }

}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if(grantResults[0]== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        Log.v(TAG,"Permission: "+permissions[0]+ "was "+grantResults[0]);
        //resume tasks needing this permission
        Save_file();
    }
}
```

Comment: Try Your Code worked Thx Man. I dont have check permission for api 23 every time

Comment: @Cool if the answer helped..kindly mark it as correct by clicking the tick sign